# How to unset environment variables from script

Tags: bash, docker, supervisord

if I need to unset an environment variable from script it used to be "sourced" like

```
. ./myscript.sh
```

or

```
source ./myscript.sh
```

But how do i make this work, if i launch this script from supervisord?

```
[program:myapp]
command=source /usr/bin/myscript.sh
...
```

does not work.

Simple example script (myscript.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
unset -v SOME_VAR
```

That's all ...

Comment: Why don't you post the content of you script, starting with the missing interpreter

Comment: I bet `command=/usr/bin/bash -c "source /usr/bin/myscript.sh"` works.

Comment: sure execution works fine, but 'unset' of environment vars doesn't

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't generally /run/ a script by using `source`, instead you'd make it executable and then run it using it's path.

However, to specifically unset a variable just use `unset`:

```
$ TEST=foo
$ echo $TEST
foo
$ unset TEST
$ echo $TEST

$
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I asked for. I know how to unset vars from command-line. Instead I am looking for a way to unset vars from within a script. Therefore the . (or source) is normally the best practice.

Comment: It's the same thing...

Comment: Sorry, Jacob but this is not true!

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.

```
root@localhost:~# cat set.sh
hello1=world1
hello2=world2

root@localhost:~# cat unset.sh
unset hello1
unset hello2

root@localhost:~# . set.sh
root@localhost:~# env | grep ^hello
hello1=world1
hello2=world2
root@localhost:~# . unset.sh
root@localhost:~# env | grep ^hello
root@localhost:~#
```